The issue with sending a message over UART
I'm trying to track a signal coming to my microcontroller, but I ran into an issue where the USB-UART converter only sends the signal from the PC when the UART is not connected to the microcontroller, meaning the converter's RX and TX are just left floating. When I connect RX and TX to the microcontroller, the signal doesn’t appear.
I’m observing the signal with a logic analyzer.
For sending, I'm using the Terminal program and a USB-TTL converter based on the CH340G.
I’ll describe the issue a bit more specifically. I’m sending a message through Terminal using the CH340G, a USB-TTL chip that isn’t connected to anything, with its pins pulled up to +3.3V. When I connect a logic analyzer to the chip, I can clearly see the signal I’m sending through Terminal. However, when I connect the USB-UART to the microcontroller and send a message via Terminal, no signal is generated; the logic analyzer shows nothing.
What could be the problem?
upd1.
Here is an USB-TTL converter schematic (source: https://oshwlab.com/makmak19992542/ch340g-usb-to-rs232-ttl-module-schematic_ks by Kritsana Sudlar). I connect pin4 of CON2 to RX of MCU, pin5 of CON2 to TX of MCU. Pin2 connected to pin 3. GND of USB-TTL conv connected to GND of MCU.


To help get an answer can you edit the question to include a schematic of how the USB-UART converter is connected to the microcontroller, including ground and power supply pins.

Many things could be wrong, add details which wires you connected and where. TX, RX and GND. What are the voltages, and do you have an RS-232 cable or TTL/CMOS cable.

Is the pin on the processor set up as an output pin?

@ChesterGillon I have added an info to the question.

Have you crossed Tx and Rx? (i.e: CH340 Tx -> MCU Rx, and vice-versa)

The value of R4 is quite high, so you may struggle with rounded edges at higher bitrates... where is your logic analyser connected? (on the CON2 side, or on the D4 side of R4?). I'd suggest that <500 Ohm would be better, as it's just a safety precaution (or lower if possible).

@Justme I don't have cables, only wires connecting the RX of the converter to the TX of the microcontroller, and similarly, the TX of the converter to the RX of the controller. Their grounds are connected. When no transmission is occurring, the unconnected converter outputs about 3.5V on the communication lines and about 3.3V when connected to the controller.

@Attie i connect analyzer right to CON2 on the converter. Do I understand correctly that R4 is just a current limiter?

"Do I understand correctly that R4 is just a current limiter?" - correct. In a well functioning setup it's not required. Try probing at the other side of R4, if the signal is present, then you've likely miswired the MCU or if you have indeed connected CON2 pin 4 to the MCU's Rx, then it's setup incorrectly (e.g: as an output).

+3.5v sounds quite high for a nominal +3.3v device!

What does your MCU board schematic looks like? Many boards already have something driving the MCU RX input, or leave it disconnected for optional use.
